# How to debug Azure swapping process (sometimes bringing site down)

Tags: azure, debugging, logging, web-applications

We have a pretty large project that is running on Azure. For some reason swap times became really slow recently, like at least 10 minutes.

Somtimes during the swap the site becomes superslow, like that it doesn't respond for minutes.
Other times the swap just doesn't work for one reason or another.

We are using `initializationPage` to warmup the most specific pages, but it doesn't seem to help.

**Question**
Is it possible to see what's going on during the swap? I'm trying to debug why it's so slow. Is there any log that I can see why it's stuck on what?

We can't deploy emergency fixes <strike>without bringing the whole site down.</strike> and sometimes the whole site goes down.

Any help to debug swapping problems would greatly appreciated.

**Update**

I found the following in 'Activity log' on the Azure Portal, but I still can't find any details or any hint what is going on exactly.

[image]

So: The resource operation completed with terminal provisioning state 'Failed'.

Where can I find details? It really annoys me that I have to buy Azure Developer support while I'm spending hundreds euros per month already on something that seems broken or at least very uninformative about what is going wrong.

Comment: What did you find from JSON? Click and scroll down to see some sort of error message. For example `statusCode": "Conflict",
        "serviceRequestId": null,
        "statusMessage": "{\"Code\":\"Conflict\",\"Message\":\"Cannot swap site slots because one of the slots is in a stopped state.\",\"Target\":null,\"Details\":[{\"Message\":\"Cannot swap site slots because one of the slots is in a stopped state.\"},{\"Code\":\"Conflict\"},{\"ErrorEntity\":{\"ExtendedCode\":\"04056\",\"MessageTemplate\":\"Cannot swap site slots because one of the slots is in a stopped state.\",\""`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> So: The resource operation completed with terminal provisioning state 'Failed'.
>
> Where can I find details?

Microsoft has a few things that may help you.

> You can view the operations for a deployment through the Azure portal.
>   You may be most interested in viewing the operations when you have
>   received an error during deployment so this article focuses on viewing
>   operations that have failed. The portal provides an interface that
>   enables you to easily find the errors and determine potential fixes.

The "**View deployment operations with Azure Resource Manager**" is directly from [Microsoft](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/resource-manager-deployment-operations) it has several steps to follow. Follow the URL: [Microsoft](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/resource-manager-deployment-operations)

I hope this helps.